# Upload photo graphql by Flutter

Tags: node.js, express, flutter, graphql, apollo-server

I use https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter package to upload Photos. It worked well but after the upgrade of packages, it crushed. The error

```
I/flutter (12390): GraphQL Errors:
I/flutter (12390): Variable "$uploadPhoto" got invalid value {}; 
Expected type Upload. Upload value invalid.: Undefined location
```

Also, maybe the problem on backEnd side 
[Node js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z81KU.png)

or maybe problem on Flutter side 
[Flutter code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfZeS.png)
I use https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker

Mutation

```
 mutation (
       $uploadPhoto:Upload 
       $childServiceIds: [String!]
       $executors: [String!]
       $institutionId: String!
       $description:String!
       $price: Float!
       $name:String!
      ){
      createService(
        institutionId: $institutionId
        description: $description
        iconImage: $uploadPhoto
        name: $name
        price: $price
        token:""
        childServiceIds: $childServiceIds
        executors: $executors
      ){
        services{ 
          _id
                    name
            price
            description
            childServiceIds
            iconLogoUrl
        }
    }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no null check.

Possibly uploadPhoto is null and your end up in type mismatch.

PS share method dart code in text not in picture.

Comment: Thank you for advice about the code.
I checked uploadPhoto is not null.